# If there is any way in Blender I can use a mathematical formula to control particle density?

Tags: python, scripting, particles, mathematics, numpy

I'm trying to visualize something in physics. I have a formula that determines the density of particles at each point in 3D space. How can I visualize this?

For example: density=1/r^2

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to particle emitter you can get a close approximation directly or run a script for greater accuracy by utilizing the curve guide force.

## Create a sphere object and add an emmision particle system to it.

[image: ![](particle%20system.png)]

## Emmission settings:

[image: ![](emit_settings.png)]

- Set the frame start and end to 1 to have all particles instantly generated.
- Set emmision source to Emit from Volume.

## Viewport Display settings:

[image: ![](vp_display.png)]

- In the viewport display options disable show emmiter.

## Field weight settings:

[image: ![](field_weight_settings.png)]

Ensure Curve guide is enabled as full field weight. (disable all others as desired for animation)*

## Add Forcefield Curve Guide:

[image: ![](Curve_guide.png)]

[image: ![](curve_guide_obj.png)]

- The curve guide object initially starts with 5 points but can be subdivided and points placed to approximate your function quickly along the x & y axis. (though infinite at 1/r^2 where r=0 isn't going to occur)
- If you require high degree of resolution & accuracy you may wish to modify the curve through a script, but it will still simply be placing sample points along the curve.

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.data.objects['CurveGuide']

spline = obj.data.splines[0]

desired_pts = 21

if len(spline.points) < desired_pts:
    spline.points.add(desired_pts - len(spline.points))

pt_start = -10
pt_end = 10
step = (pt_end - pt_start +1)/len(spline.points)

position = pt_start
for pt in spline.points:
    if position == 0:
        pt.co = Vector((position, 1/(0.001*0.001), 0.0, 1.0))
    else:
        pt.co = Vector((position, 1/(position*position), 0.0, 1.0))
    position += step
```

## Reulting particle distribution:

[image: ![](particle%20distribution2.gif)]

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) Enable Extra Objects Addon

[image]

#### 2) Add Mesh > Math Function

[image]

[image]

#### Use Geometry Nodes to display points

[image]